# Get variable from get_template_part?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is is possible to get a variable from another template?

I have a page template with the following at the top:

```
<?php echo $table_name; ?>
```

Then a bit further down the page I'm using this:

```
<?php get_template_part('governance-management'); ?>
```

Within that template is the following (along with lots of other code which shows fine):

```
<?php $table_name = "CPEL Implementation"; ?>
```

How can I echo out the `$table_name` variable in the first echo?

The problem is I'm calling a variable before it's set. Is there any way to get around that? I've tried putting the echo below the `get_template_part` but it still doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you simply have to declare your variable as `global` :

```
global $table_name;
$table_name = "CPEL Implementation";
```

If you want to use it in another template :

```
global $table_name;
echo $table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The "global" method didn't work for me. (As it is an accepted answer it maybe worked in 2012 but not in 2015?!)

I had to change the get_template_part line to this:

```
include(locate_template('content.php'));
```